# Pass function return value to reference parameter cause compilation error in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, reference, pass-by-reference

Suppose I have this function declared:

```
class A
{
...
 public:
   void setRect(Rect & rct);
...
}
```

The member `setRect` is called like this.

```
A a;
a.setRect(Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object());
```

The gcc compiler complains that no matching function found A::setRect(**Rect**)

If I call like this ,it is fine:

```
A a;
Rect rct = Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object();
a.setRect(rct);
```

Did the standard say something about this?  GCC just do not allow the first way of calling `setRect()` function?

Comment: Does `setRect` modify its parameter or not? If not, why does it take it as a non-const reference? If so, how would you get to the modified object in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is correct.

If `Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object()` returns by value, i.e. `Rect Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object()`, then for `a.setRect(Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object());`, what `Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object()` returns is a temporary which couldn't be bound to non-const lvalue reference (i.e. `Rect &`).

`rct` is a named variable and might be bound to non-const lvalue reference, so `a.setRect(rct);` works. Or if possible you could change the parameter type to const reference (i.e. `const Rect &`), which could be bound with temporary.

Comment: @ShaoboZi Oh, don't, `const` is so useful in C++. :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume `a.setRect(Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object());` function is returning by value object. Value type object stored on stack and stack of `Some_Func_Return_A_Rect_Object()` is unwind after function return. 
But you can fetch the return value(temporary object) to the const lvalue reference, rvalue reference.

You should have take `void setRect(Rect & rct);` function as `void setRect(const Rect & rct);`. Then your compilation problem will be resolved.
OR
In C++11 onward you can also take `void setRect(Rect & rct);` as rvalue reference  `void setRect(Rect && rct);`.